# Contact form. Everything should work, but it doesn't

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I have a problem with my contact form. When I fill it on my website, I get an e-mail, but fields: Name, eMail and Message remain blank in my received e-mail.

My contact complex consists of: `contacts.html` (html page on my website); `contactengine.php` (an actual form); `thanks.html` (it opens when a question is successfully posted); `unsuccessful.html` (opens when unsuccessful).

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code?

CONTACTS.HTML

```
<form id="form" form action="contactengine.php" method="post" >
   <fieldset>
     <label><input type="text" name="cf_name" value="Name" id="cf_name" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Name'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Name' ) this.value=''"></label>
     <label><input type="text" name="cf_email" value="e-Mail" id="cf_email" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='e-Mail'" onFocus="if(this.value =='e-Mail' ) this.value=''"></label  
     <label><textarea name="cf_message" id="cf_message" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Message'}" onFocus="if(this.value=='Message'){this.value=''}">Message</textarea></label>
     <div class="btns">
     <a href="contacts.html" class="link-1">Cancel</a>
     <a href="contactengine.php" class="link-1" onClick="document.getElementById('form').submit()">Submit</a></div>
   </fieldset>  
</form>
```

CONTACTENGINE.PHP

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "form@mysite.rs";
$EmailTo = "office@mysite.rs";
$Subject = "Message from website";
$cf_name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$cf_email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$cf_message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
   print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=unsuccessful.html\">";
   exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $cf_name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "e-Mail: ";
$Body .= $cf_email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $cf_message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=thanks.html\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=unsuccessful.html\">";
}
?>
```

Comment: You would have received better answers if you had used the [tag:php] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines:

```
$cf_name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$cf_email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$cf_message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message']));
```

should be changed to

```
$cf_name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['cf_name'])); 
$cf_email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['cf_email'])); 
$cf_message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['cf_message']));
```

The variable name doesn't matter, but the text inside `$_POST['']` **should be the same as the name value for the form element!**
You prefixed the names in your HTML with `cf_`, but didn't do the same in your PHP!

**EDIT:** Oops, I missed something!
You are linking to `contactengine.php` with an `<a>` link!
Your browser treats this as a regular `GET` request, **and doesn't send the data with it!**
Even though you put JavaScript code  to submit the form, **the browser's default action (to go to the link) overpowers your code**.

To fix this, either

1. Change the last `<a>` tag in `contacts.html` to `<input type="submit" value="Submit" />`, turning the link into a submit button, *or*
2. Add `; return false;` to the end of your `onclick` handler for the submitting link. This stops the browser from doing its default behavior, and submits the form.

Comment: Still the same. I think the basic problem lies within the fact that changeable fields on my website's contacts.html page aren't linked with php properly. But I have no idea what's wrong...

Comment: I think I figured out the problem this time. Look at the edit.

Comment: Cheers man, the second option solved it. Basically, the first option did it too, but I had some issues with the looks of my website. Can you explain "; return false;" more thoroughly?

Cheers once again

Comment: When you click on a link, your browser recognizes it, and navigates to the page. It _does_ run your JavaScript before loading the second page, however, your browser won't submit the form because it's already loading contactengine.php. `; return false;` tells the browser to not load the page. Now that your browser isn't loading the linked-to page, it submits the form, as you wrote in your JavaScript code. You could have also changed the `a` tag to a `span`, kept the `onclick` event handler, and styled it to look like a link.

Comment: I see. So, basically, my browser did load the page after all, even though I clearly told it to redirect and a form wasn't a form when loaded because it's purpose is not to collect the data, but to mail them. Cheers again man